# how to enable group option in azure signalr function?

Tags: azure, signalr

How to enable group option in azure signalr function, cant get the `"headers.x-ms-client-principal-id"`

```
[FunctionName("MultiplayerConnect")]
        public static async Task<SignalRConnectionInfo> GetSignalRInfo(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = Constants.Version + "/multiplayerconnect/"+"{id}")] HttpRequest req,string id,
            [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "multiplayer",UserId = "{headers.x-ms-client-principal-id}")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
        {
            var counter = await StatsFunctions.GetDayCounter();

            if (counter.Messages > Constants.DAILY_MSGS_MAX)
                return null;
            else
                return connectionInfo;
        }
```